# When is $u$-substitution allowed when it forces you out of the domain.

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve a problem that involves a periodic function $g(x)$ on the domain $[-1,1]$ (we can assume it looks the same on left and right of $y$-axis) and $f(x)=x$. To integrate it over $[-1,1]$ I need to do the $u=x+1$ substitution. However, that changes the bounds to $0$ and $2$ which $g(x)$ is not strictly defined on. Can i just extend the definition of $g$ to again be the same function on $[1,2]$ ? What stops me from defining it to be whatever there, and change the integral? That makes no sense as what $g$ looks like on $[1,2]$ should not affect the integral from $[-1,1]$

I am very confused and I would appreciate a response as to what is happening?

Comment: @MPW It can be any periodic function. The problem is actually to find a periodic function that satisfies certain criteria. To find it i used a $u$ sub which feels illegal.

Comment: The bounds of $u$ make the domain of the function you are composing with, so this should not be an issue. -- But yes, posting your work would help!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Show the integral you're trying to compute. Making a substitution doesn't change the domain of definition for a function. For example, if you have $$\int_a^bh(x)\;dx$$ and you want to substitute $u=x+c$ (so $x=u-c$), then you get $$\int_{a+c}^{b+c} h(u-c)\;du$$ and everything is still in the proper domain.

Answer (score 1):

You won't run out of the bounds. It doesn't make sense that a u-substitution would change the bounds of $g(x)$, since the "area" (under the curve) is still the same, we're just using different variable names and partition sizes.

Consider $\displaystyle \int_0^1g(x)h(x)\,dx$, where $g$ is defined on $[0,1]$. Perhaps, it becomes easier to use the substitution $\displaystyle x=\frac{u}{2}\implies dx=\frac{1}{2}\,du$.

So your integral would become $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2g\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)h\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\,du$.

Notice, the bounds are now $(0,2)$, but $g$ is still evaluated only from $0$ to $1$.